# Sharepoint + Value does not fall within the expected range + SPListItem

Tags: sharepoint

Looks like other people have had this issue, but I would like to understand how to target a column if there are spaces in a list column name when using the code below. Here is what I have:

```
    SPWeb oWebsite = SPContext.Current.Web;
    SPList oList = oWebsite.Lists["Project Info"];
    SPListItemCollection collItem = oList.GetItems("Project Description");

    if (collItem.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (SPListItem oItem in collItem)
        {
            description = oItem["Project Description"].ToString();
        }
    }
```

If I create the list field "Project Description" with underscores for the column name (Project_Description), then it works just fine, but with the code above I get an error: Value does not fall within the expected range

Looks like there is something with the display vs internal name of the column. Can someone help me with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try "Project_x0020_Description". AFAIK this works when using the web services. Not sure whether it also helps in your case.

Here is some more information: http://www.davehunter.co.uk/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=95

Answer (score 1):

Use Always the URl of the List, because URL's dont give problems like that ;)